# Can I clear all my subscribed FCM topics by calling deleteToken?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for Flutter.

I would like to be able to delete all the subscribed topics without my application having to store the subscribed topics itself on local storage.

Can I simple call deleteToken to unsubscribe from all topics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();` unsubscribes the device from all topics.

> **deleteToken method**
>
> Removes access to an FCM token previously authorized.
>
> Messages sent by the server to this token will fail.
>
> Source: [deleteToken's documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html)